# I can't find other language for Krita which is installed by snap, and there is no icon for Krita, either

Tags: icons, language-support, snap, krita

As you can see, there is English only.
[image]

As you can see, there is no icon for Krita.
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a snap installation? you easily can add the krita repository and install it this way.

Comment: You mean snap can't do it?

Comment: No just asking, snap is pretty new and there can be still more likely packaging errors occur, even the cracks have still their issue with creating snap packages. I'm running krita still installed from the repository and don't face this language problem.

Comment: Snapcraft can do it. I think this was an early version of the app snapped up... Working on a version that would solve these issues.

Answer (score 2):

The launcher icon should be there now, if you have version 3.0-snap11

The translations are going to take some work in the packaging, but it's possible to do. This was just a very basic snap config to get started with.